# Unable to add attachment to Airtable forms in Flutter Webview, any solutions?

Tags: flutter, forms, webview, updates, airtable

I have been trying to load a form from Airtable using flutter webview. But when I tried flutter webview 3.0.0 it was loading the form. But I was unable to add Image attachment.

Than I updated to the latest flutter webview 4.2.0. But still I am unable to add attachments.

[Button to go to the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCJT9.png)

[Unable to add attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGJIZ.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class NewCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewCustomer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewCustomer> createState() => _NewCustomerState();
}

class _NewCustomerState extends State<NewCustomer> {
  var loadingPercentage = 0;
  WebViewController webview = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    webview
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (url) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 0;
            });
          },
          onProgress: (progress) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = progress;
            });
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 100;
            });
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://airtable.com/shrNceygh14VGsLR2'),
      )
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Form",
          selectionColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 42, 167),
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: webview,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please add some source code?